# How can I flash a microcontroller from a GUI? (A driver software concept)

Tags: microcontroller, driver, memory

Assuming that I have three LED lights, and I have created a GUI that allows the end customers to choose which color each LED is going to display and then save it to the permanent memory of the microcontroller and these LEDs are forever going to have that same colors even if you disconnect the device. How would it be possible to do something like that? After all, when I code something I can compile it with my IDE, but how can I create a software that compiles the user settings based on a gui and then compile the new settings in order to flash them to the device?

Comment: You define a communication protocol between your micro and PC, write the PC software, and write the MCU Firmware capable of communicating this protocol. The MCU should also have a non volatile memory and your firmware should be able to write it with the settings you want it to "remember".

Comment: The firmware on the MCU that allows self-programming over an arbitrary interface is called a bootloader. Some microcontrollers have special registers/bits in ROM that you can usefor whatever. In that case, the actual bootloading of the GUI itself is different than the messages to the MCU which instruct it (via some firmware on the MCU, likely the bootloader) to set those bits appropriately.

Comment: @DKNguyen Not necessarily. A bootloader is a piece of a firmware that is loading another piece of a firmware. Here it looks doable with a single piece which can save some data to eeprom/flash

Comment: @EugeneSh. I agree. But I'm answering the question from both aspects since the OP seems unaware of the way he mashed two disparate aspects together in the question.

Comment: @Justme I don't see the issue. It's not like I only talked about the bootloader.

Comment: @DKNguyen You are right, point taken. I was more focused on the "configuring user settings" part, while you seemed to be more focused on the "flashing the firmware" part.

Comment: You could avoid a bunch of hypotheticals, if you tell us what MCU you're using.  I suspect that you are making it much harder on yourself than what's necessary.

Comment: As the real question was buried in the comments I am suggesting closing this question until OP hopefully changes it to mean what it is _really_ about.

Comment: voting to close ... reason: lacking focus

Answer (score 4):

In light of new information that this is actually not about changing LED colors but really updating MCU firmware, you would generally read MCU manufacturer documentation how to upload firmware, and the GUI part is still irrelevant as it does not matter if it is a GUI program or not.

-- 8<-- old answer below --8<--

Technically that would not be flashing a microcontroller but sending and storing user settings, and the GUI part for doing that is irrelevant how to do it on MCU.

Sure, you might want a GUI that allows user to select colors. But in the end, you need to transmit the user selection somehow to the MCU, for example as a text string "red,green,blue" or binary numbers of 1 2 3 to represent the three colors of three LEDs.

Then the MCU needs to receive that information via the interface you choose and store it somewhere.

Some MCUs have additional memory area for storing settings so you don't have to store the settings into program code area, but that is also possible. It really depends on the MCU. You could also store the settings into external memory chip and read it back when you need the settings.

So select an interface, select a protocol, and select where to store the settings. That part does not depend on any GUI, you can write such a GUI program as the last part, not first, as it is not relevant which kind of program it is that sends the info to MCU.

Answer (score 2):

Some Vendor provide cli to program their chips I know for example ST provide STlink CLI so that you can use it inside your GUI

Answer (score 0):

> how can I create a software that compiles the user settings based on a
> gui and then compile the new settings in order to flash them to the
> device?

As many people already pointed out, you are looking at the problem from completely wrong angle. There are many ways to do it much easier and/or more convenient for end user.

However since you've asked precise question I'll try to give exact answer.

When your IDE compiles your code it does not do it by itself, it calls external compiler/linker and (in case of run command) programmer. Usually the command lines it uses are clearly visible in the console window. If you copy/paste them into batch file you can run it at any time to get current source compiled and uploaded to MCU.

So, the second part of it would be to write a simple code in your GUI application that creates or replaces small header file which is included into MCU program and simply defines three colors for LEDs. In fact, the generation of this file can be easily done in the batch file itself, if you pass colors as parameters for it.

The final (optional) step of the process would be to execute batch file from the GUI when user is done changing colors. You code would either generate new header file and call batch to compile/upload, or it can directly call batch with color parameters to do everything there.

Obviously, for all this to work you'd need to have entire toolchain properly installed/configured, in addition to your GUI application and batch file. This is exactly what makes your approach wrong.

UPDATE:

following @Justme comment below, here is another option which is slightly less cumbersome.

You can generate hex/bin file in your GUI application with just a few bytes that define LED colors. Then you can use flash utility to upload these bytes into predefined address in the MCU flash or EEPROM or external flash (whatever you have available in your hardware). This is not a trivial task in that it requires understanding of uploader parameters to avoid deleting the program itself.

Comment: This approach assumes the GUI will actually compile new firmware and actually flash the new firmware to MCU. Recompiling the firmware is completely overkill approach. All you need is an existing firmware binary, edit the firmware binary for correct colors, and then flash the edited firmware to MCU. However, I don't think OP even means reflashing the firmware to begin with, but just sending and storing the user settings into EEPROM or flash.

Comment: @Justme yes, that is doable too. I've updated the answer

Comment: @Maple Thank you guys. Actually, the LEDs were just an example, what I'm actually looking to do is to is to learn how to push new software updates to products and I thought that starting with a simple LED changing GUI would be a good way to start learning about the field.

Comment: @Theprocodernotreallyxd That changes the whole nature of the question. You should have left that part out then and ask what you really wanted to ask.

Comment: @Theprocodernotreallyxd Whoa!... I hope you realize that you've just thoroughly wasted time of so many people trying to help you